# React Native : Access Component state inside a static function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a component defined like this

```
export class A extends Component{
   constructor(props){
     this.state = {
        scene:0
     }
   }
  static changeScene(scene){
     this.setState({scene:scene})
  }
}
```

I want to call change scene from anywhere using `A.changeScene(sceneVal)`
  to change the scene in A. the problem is i can't access this.setState i got this error `Unhandled JS Exception: this.setState is not a function.`

I am sure that the A component is already mounted. I can bypass this error by defining a global variable `var self = null;` and inside the constructor  `self =  this` in the constructor but i want a better way to rosolve this problem

Comment: Can you be sure, that there is only a single instance of component `A`? If yes, then assigning `this` to a static variable seems reasonable. If not, then then you need to rethink the question.

Comment: I'm not sure if static functions need `bind` to keep the context. You could give it a try

Comment: static functions will never have access to the `this` your non static functions have access to. Think about non-static methods, as each instance have it, and think about static methods as the class has it.

Comment: yes i am sure it will be one instance.

Comment: i tried to bind the static func but noway it give me an erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is, if you use `static function` then a `static` method won't be able to access `this` inside that function. You should avoid using `static` function. `Static` methods have no access to the values, properties, and methods defined on an instance of the `class` using `this`.

Check this article: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx

Comment: is defining a global var self = this a bad idea than ? it will be no more than one instance of A . thanks :)

Comment: you can use the global variable, but i think it will be better to use some architecture like redux/flux you can easily do this kind of task. Lets say from any component you want to change something in A, pass the value to store the listen the changes in comp A. it will be a more proper way :)