# React Navigation header button that controls rendering of the screen

Tags: react-navigation

*PLEASE NOTE that 'this' is not accessible from a static function:* [React Native : Access Component state inside a static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373580/react-native-access-component-state-inside-a-static-function/42373700#42373700)

---

I am trying to define a button in the screen's header that, when clicked, will affect rendering, and will be replaced with another icon.

It is an old app, still using react navigation 3.

I didn't know how to do the following things:

- modify the component's state from a function that is activated when the button is pressed
- modify the screen parameter from this function

What I managed to implement is the following lame and embarrassing way to do it:

- When the button is clicked, a static function is executed, which modfies a static variable
- periodic code is fired in componentDidMount that checks whether the static detailedDisplay variable has been modified. If it has been modified, this code sets a state variable that affects rendering. This periodic code also modifies the screen parameter which changes the icon in the header (because, as I wrote above, I also failed to set the parameter from the static function).

How can this be done in not-so-lame way?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
...
export default class Messages extends Component {
...
var detailedDisplay = false;
...
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerRight: //navigation.getParam('detailedDisplay', false) ?
        detailedDisplay ?
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay(navigation)}>
          <Icon name={"check-circle"} />
        </TouchableOpacity> :
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay()}>
          <Icon name={"comment"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>,
    };
  };

  static toggleDisplay(navigation) {
    detailedDisplay = !detailedDisplay;
    // the following statement gave the error "cannot read property 
    //    'setParams' of undefined", so I am setting it below.
    // navigation.setParams({ detailedDisplay });
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      detailedDisplay: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (detailedDisplay !== this.state.detailedDisplay) {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ detailedDisplay });
        this.setState({ detailedDisplay });
      }
    }, 500);
  }
  ...
  return (
      <View>
        { this.state.detailedDisplay ?
          {this.renderConcise()} :
          {this.renderDetailed()}
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderDetailed() {
    ...
  }

  renderConcise() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you  can try to use your  state inside your `navigationOption` method

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerRight: //navigation.getParam('detailedDisplay', false) ?
        this.state.detailedDisplay ?
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay(navigation)}>
          <Icon name={"check-circle"} />
        </TouchableOpacity> :
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.toggleDisplay()}>
          <Icon name={"comment"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>,
    };
  };
```

And then change your state in the `toggleDisplay` method

```
static toggleDisplay(navigation) {
    this.setState(state=> detailedDisplay:!state.detailedDisplay)
    // the following statement gave the error "cannot read property 
    //    'setParams' of undefined", so I am setting it below.
    // navigation.setParams({ this.state.detailedDisplay });
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373580/react-native-access-component-state-inside-a-static-function/42373700#42373700

Answer (score 0):

You can try and keep the param and a state variable in sync.
An example POC is [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@spiderx/b67040)

Here, I have tried to keep the state toggleVariable and the param value in sync but updating them through a common setter, and on Component Mount it will just be the same as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read properties of this because this in JS is dynamic, and when you pass function as callback this is lost. There is 2 solutions that i know:
One of them bind this using bind method:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      detailedDisplay: false,
    };
    this.toggleDisplay = this.toggleDisplay.bind(this);
    this.navigationOptions = this.navigationOptions.bind(this) 
  }
```

Now you can use non-static methods and you can access react state and methods in them:

```
navigationOptions({ navigation }) {
     // somewhere in code <button onPress={this.toggleDisplay}><button>
     // this.props this.state this.setState is available here
  };

toggleDisplay(navigation) {
    // this.props this.state this.setState is available here
    // this.props.navigation.setParams() is available too 
  }
```

Finally, you can change the detailedDisplay state and screen params in toggleDisplay function. So when you'll press button state'll be changed and your commponent'll be re-rendered.

Additional
Second way to do it is to call method in a function:

```
onPress={() => this.toggleDiaplay()}
```

Here you must also use non-static methods, and this will work the same way as the first solution with bind.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something like this:

**UPDATED:** removed static from the toggleDisplay and added Class reference in the static function.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Octicons';
...
export default class Messages extends Component {
...
    state = {
        detailedDisplay: false,
    };
...
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerRight: navigation.getParam('detailedDisplay', false) ?
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Messages.toggleDisplay()}>
          <Icon name={"check-circle"} />
        </TouchableOpacity> :
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Messages.toggleDisplay()}>
          <Icon name={"comment"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>,
    };
  };

  toggleDisplay() {
    this.setState({detailedDisplay: !this.state.detailedDisplay})
    this.props.navigation.setParams({detailedDisplay: true});
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // setInterval(() => {
    //   if (detailedDisplay !== this.state.detailedDisplay) {
    //     this.props.navigation.setParams({ detailedDisplay });
    //     this.setState({ detailedDisplay });
    //   }
    // }, 500);
  }
  ...
  return (
      <View>
        { this.state.detailedDisplay ?
          {this.renderConcise()} :
          {this.renderDetailed()}
        }
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderDetailed() {
    ...
  }

  renderConcise() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42373580/react-native-access-component-state-inside-a-static-function/42373700#42373700

Comment: @Yossi Updated my answer

Comment: I appreciate the effort! I am getting "Messages.toggleDisplay is not a function", which is understandable, since toggleDisplay is not defined as a static function.